# Using email MFA for Cognito with Hosted UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I would like to enable email MFA for my User Pool. Cognito doesn't support email MFA natively, but I found an [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/extending-amazon-cognito-with-email-otp-for-2fa-using-amazon-ses/) from AWS which shows you how to implement it using a few Lambda functions.

I followed that tutorial and created all of the required Lambda functions, but I still don't understand how to implement it correctly.

The tutorial assumes you developed your own sign-up page, but in my case I'm using hosted-UI, which only enables me to edit it's CSS.

I'm not sure how to apply what the article says to my use-case. I have SES enabled and verified which will handle the emails and I'm also able to register an account in my hosted UI. The only problem is that when I try to login, I get an error saying "No MFA mechanism registered in the account". I'm guessing the Lambda functions are not triggered.

Comment: After talking to AWS Support, if you're using the Hosted UI feature, you cannot use email MFA. So bottom line you need front+backend skills to implement email MFA in Cognito, at least until AWS implements this method of authentication in Cognito.

Comment: have you implemented this am struck with the same